# This coupon is assigned to some other user, Please verify

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Woocommerce is giving the following error whenever a user tries to apply a coupon.

> This coupon is assigned to some other user, Please verify !

I have tried everything. I have deleted all the coupons and then created them. I have tried to use coupon without any setting. Nothing is working.

What could be the possible cause of this?

Is this a woocommerce bug?

Comment: Hi,Have check the woocommerce plugin but it doesn't seem to have any statement like this. This might be caused because of some other plugin which is restricting. Try activating plugin one by one and check in between them to know which plugin is causing this problem.

Comment: I guess this is because of the sign up discount plugin. I deactivated it, and it worked well.